# Query criteria to replace records with multiple subtotals

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2016

> **EDIT** comments pointed out my question was too broad so I have done my best to focus it.

Trying to build a finance tracker in `MS Access 2016` for spending analysis. I want to bring together multiple records from various bank accounts each one having a respective table that is identical to the bank statements (for ease of correcting). So lets say I have `Bank1-T` and `Bank2-T`. All bank account tables will have identical fields.

However I would also like to have the ability to, on occasion (where needed), replace certain records with subtotals to increase spending tracking granularity.

> **For example** say I went to the gas station and paid for petrol as well
>   as lunch in the same payment, I would like `Bank1-T` to
>   have the single entry for payment to the petrol station, but to have
>   `Accounts-T` have the separate entries for payment of petrol and food.

Since I don't want to edit the bank account tables, I though I'd go ahead and store the split subtotals for payments in a table `PayDetails-T`. As there would only be a few payments I would store in `PayDetails-T`, how would I go about setting up a `Query` that brings together the payments from the various bank tables, and replaces the specific payment records from the bank tables with the ones in `PayDetails-T`? Can it be done in a single `Query` or would multiple be needed?

Comment: This question involves database and application design.  Not only are there multiple ways to accomplish what you ask, this will solicit opinionated and extensive answers.  This type of questions is either too broad and/or off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: By the way, the term "join" for a relational database management system (RDMS) like Access has a particular meaning.  It means to relate two tables in a query, often via a primary and foreign key.  However, your question implies that records from multiple tables are being copied into the `Accounts-T` table.  At the least, it is not clear that the explanations follow standard RDMS terminology.  This may confuse others who regularly design and program DB systems.  It also indicates that your suggested design is *not properly normalized* according to relational database standards.

Comment: Ah, I feared as much, I'm new to access and databases, so I was certain I was probably missing the correct terminology and some understanding. I did a 15 hour course on it. But haven't found a way to actually use what I've learned to achieve the desired result in any form. Any help towards one solution is more than I could hope for.

Comment: I will look into normalising my database, and see to edit the phrasing of my question. Thank you for the explanation of how it could cause confusion!

Comment: @CPerkins does the question feel more correct/less broad in this rephrasing?

Comment: A direct answer to the last questions is that it will almost certainly need multiple queries and/or (nested) subqueries.  First an aggregate query must identify (i.e. select) records with split entries.  Then using the result of the first, two other queries must separately select details of non-split records and details of those which are split.  Finally the query results must combine the two queries with a UNION query. -- More specifics are still not possible since table schema was not shared, but also rephrasing still does not eliminate concerns about normalization, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185843/discussion-between-c-perkins-and-fiztban).

Comment: You are basically describing a double-entry accounting system. Might be more cost-effective to buy an OTS app like QuickBooks or use MS Money which might actually be free.

Comment: As noted by @CPerkins, a single query will likely not provide the output you want but a report might by using its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs in textboxes.

Comment: Instead of multiple tables for bank accounts, should probably be 1 table with an additional field for the bank account number or actually the record ID from BankAccounts table.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @June7. The reason for not going with an app, I have been looking into them, is that they don't offer the type of category based analyses I would like. Living in the [UK doesn't currently offer any ability to link bank accounts with apps](https://www.reddit.com/r/UKPersonalFinance/comments/7k6szl/ukbased_personal_finance_software/drc0kjm/ "reddit: UK-Based Personal Finance Software") so I am left with having to manually enter data or manipulating `.csv` files. Putting these together created the opportunity for me to learn access and DBs and make what I need.

Comment: @June7 thank you for suggesting `MS Money`, I didn't know about it. It is now called [Money Plus Sunset Deluxe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20738 "Microsoft Download page") the previous versions and online services have been discontinued and this was the last free version they released in 2010. According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/povertyfinance/comments/89xw4k/free_professional_personal_finance_software/ "reddit: Free professional Personal Finance software (Windows only)") it is indeed a tool worth looking into so I will give it a go as well.